# Finding a relatively large number which forces a small remainder

Tags: nt.number-theory

I was interested in the following question, which I am not sure if
it is true or not. I would appreciate any answers or references. Thank you!
(Please note this is the revised version of the original question asked
as pointed out by the comments of Mr/Ms The Masked Avenger)

Suppose I have real numbers $0 < \theta < \gamma < 1$.
Does there exist some absolute constant $C> 0$ such
that the following holds for $X$ sufficiently large?:
If $X > q > X^{\gamma}$, then we can find $ X^{\theta}/ \log X < k < X^{\theta}\log X$
such that 
$q \equiv r (\text{mod }k)$ and $0 \leq r \leq C \log X$.
(or possibly the same statement where we replace $\log X$ with $X^{\epsilon}$)

Comment: No.  Let K be the product of all the candidate k in the range specified when X and theta are given.  For your favorite integer A let q= AK + C + 1.  Then q will be = C+1 mod k for any of your desired k.  When X gets big enough, your constant C does not work.

Comment: Even if you further restricted q , say q  at most X, I would be surprised to find a result.  I  can imagine C depending on logX though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I greatly appreciate it! I think I am going to change the question accordingly.

Comment: As you wish.  I would appreciate the revised version giving a nod to the comments, so that what I said earlier is not totally out of place.

Comment: Hope this works! Thank you for your helpful comments!